# Multiple jquery ui tooltip positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I was using Jquery UI tooltips for my project and wanted to position tooltips for the entire document except divisions with a class in a certain way.

```
$( document ).not(".t_l_overview").tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "center top",
        at: "center bottom+5"
      },
      show: {
        duration: "fast"
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "hide"
      }
 });

$(".t_l_overview").tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "left+15 center",
        at: "right center"
      },
      show: {
        duration: "fast"
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "hide"
      }
 });
```

The problem is if I use either one of this at a time, it is working but both are not working together. If i use both in the code, tooltip gets applied only to divisions with class t_l_overview . Any idea, what I might be doing wrong and any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `not` selector. `$(document).not(".t_l_overview")` is the empty array, so you're not actually setting the "default".

If you want to select all DOM elements that do not have the class `t_l_overview`, you can use the syntax:

```
$("*").not(".t_l_overview").tooltip({ ... });
```

or

```
$("html").not(".t_l_overview").tooltip({ ... });
```

or

```
$("body").not(".t_l_overview").tooltip({ ... });
```

The last one is probably what you want, since I'm guessing you don't care about setting tooltips on `<head>` or `<script>` elements.

You can also set a default tooltip and override it for a specific element set like so:

```
$(document).tooltip({ ... }); // default
$(".t_l_overview").tooltip({ ... }); // override for .t_l_overview
```

Subsequent calls to `tooltip()` will override whatever's already set on those elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But may i know why $(document) does not work?

Comment: `document` returns a document object, not the set of DOM elements that comprise the `document`. From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document): "The Document interface ... provides functionality which is global to the document." By contrast, "The `Document.documentElement` ... returns the Element that is the root element of the document (for example, the `<html>` element for HTML documents)."  So you could also use `$(document.documentElement).not(".t_l_overview")` if you want. A bit of a subtle distinction.